# Verify Stokes' Theorem, example

Tags: vector-analysis, solution-verification

[image]

For this question, I have found $Curl F$, which is $xi - (y-3)j - k$. But for the equation of the plane, is it $z = 0$? If I continue, the circulation will become $2$, is that correct? I am confused.